# Error to push a ViewController from other project

Tags: c#, ios, uiviewcontroller, xamarin, pushviewcontroller

In the first project I have a `UIButton`. When I touch it, will be open other `UIViewController` from another project. But I have a problem:

Here's is my code to the first project, I will use it to call other `UIViewcontroller` from another project

```
public partial class SomeSoluctionViewController : UIViewController
{
public SomeSoluctionViewController (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
{
}

        public override void ViewDidLoad ()
            {
                base.ViewDidLoad ();
                PushedClassController pushedclass = PushedClass.AppDelegate.Storyboard.InstantiateViewController ("PushedClass") as PushedClassController;

                CallButton.TouchUpInside += (object sender, EventArgs e) => {
                    this.NavigationController.PushViewController (pushedclass, true);
                };

                // Perform any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
            }
    }
```

**I use PushViewController as Xamarin's site instructed**

I instanciate the second class with the identifier.

**On PushedClassController’s AppDelegate:**

```
public static UIStoryboard Storyboard = UIStoryboard.FromName ("MainStoryboard", null);
```

**I use it above.**

**Here's is the pushedView from the second project:**

```
 namespace PushedClass
            {
              ** [Register ("PushedClass")]**
                public partial class PushedClassController : UIViewController
                {
                    public PushedClassController (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
                    {
                    }
                }
            }
```

Registred with "PushedClass"

The log: **Objective-C exception thrown. Name: NSInvalidArgumentException Reason: Storyboard () doesn't contain a view controller with identifier 'PushedClass'**

Answer (score 0):

Open the pushed project in xamarin.

Select the view controller you want to display by clicking on the black bar at the bottom.

In the designers property pad under identity specify a unique ID for **Storyboard ID** and **Restoration ID** to `PushedClass`.